# SQL - select most recent employee information, based on Date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to execute a simple code, which looks like what is shown below.

```
SELECT MR.ID_NUMBER
, MR.LAST_NAME
, MR.FIRST_NAME
, MR.EMAIL_ADDRESS
, MR.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS
, MR.assignment_start_Date
, AD.Address_line1
, AD.Town_Or_City



FROM Master_Rv MR
, Address_Details_v AD


WHERE Last_Name = 'Test'
and AD.Person_ID = MR.PERSON_ID
```

When I run this code, Multiple rows of data are produced. I only want to retrieve the data with the most recent 'Assignment_Start_Date' if that is possible? I hope that makes sense.

I have done my research, but can not seem to get my head around it, hence why I have asked here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you need to use `group by` and some `max(MR.assignment_start_Date)`

Comment: Hi @valentin . What do you mean?

Comment: if several rows have same "Assignment_Start_Date" ? what row do you need ?

Answer (score 1):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The simplest answer to your question is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT MR.ID_NUMBER, MR.LAST_NAME, MR.FIRST_NAME,
       MR.EMAIL_ADDRESS, MR.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS, MR.assignment_start_Date,
       AD.Address_line1, AD.Town_Or_City
FROM Master_Rv MR JOIN
     (SELECT ad.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Assignment_Start_Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Address_Details_v AD
     ) AD
     ON AD.Person_ID = MR.Person_ID
WHERE MR.Last_Name = 'Test' AND seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have tried running what you posted above, but I seem to get the following error message 'FROM keyword not found where expected'. And I think this seems to refer to 'DESC as seqnum'. Do you know why this is?

Apologies if I sound like a complete amateur, I am very new to this!

Comment: @Chris_Finnerty Move the ')' after 'DESC'

Comment: I have moved the ) after the Desc and I am still having problems. Could this be due to the fact I am using a view instead of a Table? @Mottor

Comment: When I click execute, It brings my attention to 'Order BY Assignment_Start_Date' and the message that pops up is 'Invalid Identifier'

Comment: Which version from Oracle do you have?  SELECT * FROM V$VERSION

Comment: I have Oracle 11i @Mottor

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MR.ID_NUMBER
, MR.LAST_NAME
, MR.FIRST_NAME
, MR.EMAIL_ADDRESS
, MR.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS
, MR.assignment_start_Date
, AD.Address_line1
, AD.Town_Or_City



FROM Master_Rv MR
, Address_Details_v AD


WHERE Last_Name = 'Test'
and AD.Person_ID = MR.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY MR.assignment_start_Date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

this will order your records to the latest assignment_start_Date and limit your rows to 10 latest data,
but you should use JOIN for effective code instead of , in "FROM"

Comment: This is Oracle. The limit clause here is 'FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY' and exists only from Oracle 12.1 above.

Answer (score 0):

With sub select we are getting the  max assignment start date for the person with the same person_id and then is used to get only this record.

```
SELECT MR.ID_NUMBER
, MR.LAST_NAME
, MR.FIRST_NAME
, MR.EMAIL_ADDRESS
, MR.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS
, MR.assignment_start_Date
, AD.Address_line1
, AD.Town_Or_City
FROM Master_Rv MR
, Address_Details_v AD
WHERE mr.Last_Name = 'Test'
and MR.assignment_start_Date = (select max(assignment_start_Date) from Master_Rv where person_id=mr.person_id)   
and AD.Person_ID = MR.PERSON_ID
```